# Is this figure of quasiconvex function correct? (Figure 3.10 in Nonlinear Programming by Bazaraa, Sherali, and Shetty)

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I was looking for a clear definition of quasiconvex functions and came across Figure 3.10 in Nonlinear Programming by Bazaraa, Sherali, and Shetty 2006. I understand a property of of quasiconvex functions is that they are unimodal around the minimum. [Figure 3.10a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpWmj.png) is this case shows two minimums which clearly violates the unimodality property and even violates the definition listed in the book.
Could someone kindly comment whether this figure is correct or not?

Comment: A quasi convex function is not necessarily unimodal. (a) is not quasiconvex. The picture is wrong.

Comment: Could you kindly refer a source on when quasiconvex functions are not unimodal? According to Boyd and Vandenberghe' Convex Optimization this is one of the ways quasiconvex functions are defined, at least in the one dimensional sense.

Comment: A function is quasi convex **iff** the level sets are convex. So the indicator function of $[0,1]$ is quasi convex but not unimodal.

Comment: I have never seen unimodality as a requirement for quasi convexity. I would be surprised if Stephen has defined it in any other way?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but see page 94 in https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf. He wrote a function is called quasiconvex (or unimodal) and then goes on with the definition of the sublevel sets.

Comment: Wow. I am very surprised.

Comment: It's also in the definition of quasiconvex functions on Wikipedia.

Comment: The definition is the one I have (always) seen. However, there are lots of quasi convex functions that are not unimodal.

Comment: One last question please, could you kindly refer to a formal definition of unimodality? I think what I understand is a simplified version of the truth.

Comment: Good catch :-). I suspect that equating quasi convexity and unimodality was unintended.

Comment: There are various definitions, the one I would go with is in Tim's 2nd last comment in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/149476/27978.

Comment: However, just to address your question, (a) is neither unimodal not quasi convex.

Comment: Great, many thanks.

Comment: I also came across this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1454610/578642. Plotting the function in 3D makes the concept crystal clear.

Comment: Nice. I am quite surprised by the (unimodal) in the B&V definition.